# Cors request method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache, request, cors

I'm using Cors requests to communicate between my client and server placed in two different domain.

I configurate my apache http server this way it's using SSL :

```
//with AJAX withCredentials=true (cookies sent, SSL allowed...)
SetEnvIfNoCase ORIGIN (.*) ORIGIN=$1
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE" 
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ORIGIN}e"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Accept-Charset,X-Accept,Content-Type"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L,E=HTTP_ORIGIN:%{HTTP:ORIGIN}]
```

My ajax request is like this :

```
$.ajax({   url: URL,
                        type: 'PUT',
                      xhrFields: {
                           withCredentials: true
                        },
                        crossDomain: true,
                        data: userPreferences, 
                        success: function() { }
                    });
$.ajax({   url: URL,
                        type: 'GET',
                      xhrFields: {
                           withCredentials: true
                        },
                        crossDomain: true,                              
                        success: function() { }
                    });
```

The result of this configuration is, my get request is working but not my put request,i get the following error in google chrome console ( itried it with firefox )

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://URL. Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods.
```

How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have misstyped this line on my apache config

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE"
```

i typed method without S that's why i got this error :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://URL. Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods.
```

Anyway all the configurations i wrote above is a tested/working solution to enable cors with SSL.